# psql: error: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: No such file or directory

Tags: sql, linux, ubuntu, postgresql, psql

```
postgres@vosmottor-H370M-DS3H:~$ psql
psql: error: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Ставил так:

```
sudo apt install postgresql postgresql-contrib
```

Как исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала что дает команда?

```
sudo service postgresql status
```

Удали все

```
sudo apt --purge remove postgresql-12 postgresql-client-12 postgresql-client-common postgresql-common
```

Потом

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/postgresql/
sudo rm -rf /var/log/postgresql/
sudo rm -rf /etc/postgresql/
sudo userdel -r postgres
sudo groupdel postgres
sudo apt autoremove -y
```

Потом установка

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib
```

Проверить

```
pg_isready
```

Должно быть `/var/run/postgresql:5432`

Comment: `● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor pr>
     Active: inactive (dead) since Sat 2020-08-22 14:34:53 MSK; 53min ago
    Process: 14368 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 14368 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)`

Comment: ?????????????????

Comment: Он же пишет тебе - Active: inactive (dead) since Sat 2020-08-22 14:34:53 MSK; Т.е. не активный сервис, попробуй рестарт. Ты вообще его стартовал?

Comment: `service postresql start` ?

Comment: `Failed to restart postgres.service: Unit postgres.service not found.`

Comment: Для начала да просто старт

Comment: `Failed to restart postgres.service: Unit postgres.service not found.` ?

Comment: Чем завершилась установка?  Есть ли postrgesql в /usr/lib/ ?

Comment: ага............

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112117/discussion-between---and-victor-vosmottor).